# How do you assign a value from ng-repeat in AngularJS?

Tags: mysql, angularjs, forms

I have this code:

```
<ul ng-repeat="codes in response">
  <li ng-if="((codes.branch == formData.branches.alias) && (codes.taken == 0))">
    <strong>{{codes.id}}</strong> 
    {{codes.code}}
  </li>
</ul>
```

This checks if the code is taken from the database. Otherwise, it is displayed here. What I want to do now is to randomize the codes that are not yet taken and pick just one of those randomize codes and assign it to variable where I will then pass to a form data to store in a row along with the registered user's information. **How do I pass values from ng-repeat to pass to the form then to the database?**

Answer (score 0):

Here's a conceptual answer:

1. In every ng-repeat loop, check if code is not taken. If not taken, push into Array UntakenCodes
2. At the end of the loop, you have a list of untaken codes in an array.
3. When your form submit happens, use a code at random (use Javascript's Math function to pick out one code from within the index bounds of the UntakenCodes array), and push that into the DB.

> Math.floor((Math.random() * upperBound) + lowerBound);

Where upperBound is the array length and lowerBound is 0